# C# Wrapper for linphone

Tags: c#, .net, wrapper, voip, linphone

I am working on a project to build a VoIP software running on Windows Platform. We are using C# as our main programming language.

I am currently looking for an open source library that help me to handle VoIP staff, so I can simply use it. Then I comes to linphone. However, I have a lot of question to make it work.

1. How to compile the source on Windows, any step by step tutorial?
2. I know liblinphone is the core and makes it easy handle VoIP staff. But I don't know the way to use it?
3. Is there any tutorial to use the linphone SDK in Visual Studio 2010?
4. Is there any existing VoIP SDK written in C#?

Thank you very much.

Comment: any news on this one? im also coming the web....

Answer (score 0):

A simple c# wrapper for linphone can be found here https://github.com/bedefaced/sipdotnet. You can use precompiled binaries of linphone for Windows to use this wrapper.